# Add items to list of string array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  try to add a string array to a list of string arrays

I tried `list.add` but didnt work

```
List<string[,]> stringList=new List<string[,]>();
stringList.Add({"Vignesh","26"},{"Arul","27"});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you need more than 1 dimension in the inner arrays?

```
List<string[]> stringList = new List<string[]>(); // note just [] instead of [,]
stringList.Add(new string[] { "Vignesh", "26" } );
stringList.Add(new string[] { "Arul", "27" } );
```

or

```
List<string[]> stringList = new List<string[]>
{
    new string[] { "Vignesh", "26" }
    new string[] { "Arul", "27" } 
};
```

---

If yes then:

```
List<string[,]> stringList = new List<string[,]>();
stringList.Add(new string[,] { { "Vignesh" }, { "26" } } );
stringList.Add(new string[,] { { "Arul" }, { "27" } } );
```

or

```
List<string[,]> stringList = new List<string[,]>
{
    new string[,] { { "Vignesh" }, { "26" } },
    new string[,] { { "Arul" }, { "27" } }
};
```

---

But I'd rather have a custom type:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; } // or of type string if you will
}

List<Person> personList = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Vignesh", Age = 26 }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create [rectangular array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s7e8s029(v=vs.80).aspx) but you are trying to pass [single dimensional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0.aspx) of strings instead of rectangular array.

```
List<string[,]> stringList=new List<string[,]>();
stringList.Add(new string[,] {{"Vignesh","26"},{"Arul","27"}});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string[,]> list = new List<string[,]> ();
list.Add(new string[,] { {"Vignesh","26"},{"Arul","27"} });
```

You're missing a bracket around your items